# Double role WiFi SoftAP

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, driver, firmware

I know the purpose of softAP in WiFi.

While enabling the softAP WiFi playing a host role we cant activate to client role till deactivate the softAP.

Why we can't design the double role softAP, which means why can't we activate our WiFi to play client and host at same time ?

If we do, what kind of problem we happen to face, is't possible?

Because in GSM we are creating virtual multiplexing ports for data,call,SMS etc.., like wise why can't we develop any firmware do perform like this for WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's possible and it exists for various NICs. It's more complex because double mode requires handling the coexistence of both links.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft added a feature called "Virtual Wi-Fi" to Windows 7 and later operating systems, which enabled a Wi-Fi card to act as both a Wi-Fi client and a wireless access point simultaneously. Although a relatively fresh concept, new computers with Windows 7 and above were now being released with "Virtual WiFi" as a default program, making personal computing less complicated without the need for a second device.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftAP)